# google_sql_database_instance Error waiting for Create Instance when creating multiple instances with private IPs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Ok so let me see if I can explain this correctly. I'm trying to create more than one Cloud SQL instance each with private IP addresses:

vpc.tf

```
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name = var.name
  # routing_mode            = var.routing_mode
  # auto_create_subnetworks = true
}

resource "google_compute_global_address" "private_ip_block" {
  name          = google_compute_network.vpc.name
  purpose       = "VPC_PEERING"
  address_type  = "INTERNAL"
  prefix_length = var.cidr
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.name
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "vpc_connection" {
  network = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
  service = "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"
  reserved_peering_ranges = [
    google_compute_global_address.private_ip_block.name
  ]
}
```

db.tf

```
resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  name     = var.database_name
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
  region           = var.instance_region
  database_version = var.database_version
  settings {
    tier              = var.instance_settings["tier"]
    availability_type = "REGIONAL"
    backup_configuration {
      enabled                        = true
      start_time                     = "00:00"
      transaction_log_retention_days = 2
      backup_retention_settings {
        retention_unit   = "COUNT"
        retained_backups = 3
      }
    }
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled = false
      # private_network = var.vpc_name
      private_network = "projects/${var.project_id}/global/networks/${var.vpc_name}"
    }
  }

  deletion_protection = false
}

resource "google_sql_user" "user" {
  name     = "${var.database_name}-user"
  instance = google_sql_database_instance.instance.name
  type     = "CLOUD_IAM_USER"
  depends_on = [
    google_sql_database_instance.instance
  ]
}
```

Both of these are modules that are being called from a `main.tf`, and I'm using a map of objects to create the instances but only creating 1 vpc.

This succeeds if I set the IP addresses to public, but *one* of the instances will fail when assigning to the private net with the message:

```
╷
│ Error: Error waiting for Create Instance: 
│ 
│ 
│   with module.db["my_database"].google_sql_database_instance.instance,
│   on modules/db/db.tf line 13, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance":
│   13: resource "google_sql_database_instance" "instance" {
│ 
╵
```

The failure occurs about a minute into creating the instances. They both appear to start creating normally, and then about a minute in, one of them stops being logged to stdout, and after the other completes, the error appears. The GCP console simply says an unknown error has occurred. Like I said, this will work just fine when the IPs are public, so it *must* be my private networking config, right? Is there a race condition if they both try to assign the same IP address perhaps? Should I create these sequentially rather than in a `for_each` or maybe add a random delay?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone stumbles across this, this is apparently a known bug:

[How to fix "An Unknown Error Occurred" when creating multiple Google Cloud SQL instances with private IP simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990713/how-to-fix-an-unknown-error-occurred-when-creating-multiple-google-cloud-sql-i/55991852#55991852)

Issue:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/3069